# Как отменить :hover при клике

Tags: javascript, css, hover, click

При наведении на слово меню, появляется меню. Если убрать мышку с меню, оно плавно исчезнет. Я не понимаю, как можно при клике на меню с пунктами закрыть его.
Мне пришло в голову только добавлять класс при клике, а в css написать, что показывать меню, если у элемента если нету класса `.disable`
Но при таком решении класс `.disable` остаётся у элемента, и меню не появляется при наведении.
Я попробовал ловить событие `transitionend` и убирать у  элемента класс disable, но меню появляется заново

```css
.menu:hover .menu__wrapper:not(.disable) {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
menu__wrapper.addEventListener('click', () => {
 menu__wrapper.classList.add('disable');
});

menu__wrapper.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
 menu__wrapper.classList.remove('disable');
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.menu {
 max-width: 80px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

.menu span {
 display: block;
}

.menu__wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 right: 3px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 border: 1px solid red;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 transition: visibility .2s ease-in-out,
                    opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu__item {
 padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
}

.menu__item:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.menu:hover .menu__wrapper:not(.disable) {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span class="menu">
 <span>Меню</span>
 <div class="menu__wrapper" id="menu__wrapper">
  <div class="menu__item">1 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">2 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">3 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">4 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">5 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">6 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">7 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">8 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
 </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Легче всего вообще-то  для hover заготовить отдельный класс который удалять при необходимости, вот это проще

Comment: Да, я так и сделал, написал ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Легче всего оказалось прописать в `JS` наведение и отведение мыши, заместо `:hover` в `CSS`, а также при клике убирать класс
1) При наведение мышки добавляется класс(`.active`), который отвечает за появлению меню, а также добавлять `style.cursor = pointer`, чтобы мышка была того вида, которой можно кликнуть
2) При отведении этот класс удаляется
3) При клике этот класс также удаляется и добавляется `style.cursor = default`
Без манипуляций с курсором, при клике на меню(закрытии), если не двигать мышкой, то курсор останется таким, которым можно кликнуть, если в `CSS` было прописано, что у блока `cursor: pointer`

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
let menu__wrapper = menu.querySelector('.menu__wrapper');

menu.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
 menu__wrapper.classList.add('active');
 menu__wrapper.style.cursor = 'pointer';
});

menu.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
 menu__wrapper.classList.remove('active');
});

menu__wrapper.addEventListener('click', () => {
 menu__wrapper.classList.remove('active');
 menu__wrapper.style.cursor = 'default';
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.menu {
 max-width: 80px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

.menu span {
 display: block;
}

.menu__wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 right: 3px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 border: 1px solid red;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 transition: visibility .2s ease-in-out,
    opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu__wrapper.active {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}

.menu__item {
 padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
}

.menu__item:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="menu">
 <span>Меню</span>
 <div class="menu__wrapper">
  <div class="menu__item">1 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">2 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">3 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">4 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">5 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">6 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">7 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">8 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
  <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
 </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Написано с использованием JQuery. Хочу сразу заметить, что в строковой тег span нельзя вставлять блочные теги.

```js
$('.menu__wrapper').click(function(){
      $('.menu__wrapper').css('visibility', 'hidden')
});
$('.text__menu').hover(function(){
     $('.menu__wrapper').css('visibility', 'visible')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
        <span class="text__menu">Меню</span>
        <div class="menu__wrapper">
            <div class="menu__item">1 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">2 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">3 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">4 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">5 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">6 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">7 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">8 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
            <div class="menu__item">9 текст</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```